# Help me understand and compute a Fréchet derivative in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, lp-spaces, frechet-derivative

Let $V$ and $W$ be normed vector spaces, and $U \subset V$ be an open subset of $V .$ A function $F: U \rightarrow W$ is called Fréchet differentiable at $f \in U$ if there exists a bounded linear operator $A_f: V \rightarrow W$ such that
$$
\lim _{\|h\| \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|F(f+h)-F(f)-A_f (h)\|_{W}}{\|h\|_{V}}=0
$$

That is the definition we find in most textbooks. First question: is that definition equivalent to saying

$$A_f (g)=\lim _{\|h\| \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|F(f+gh)-F(f)\|_{W}}{\|h\|_{V}} ?$$

I am interested in the case $V=U=L^2(\mathbb R)$, $W=\mathbb R$, $F(f)=\int_\mathbb R |f(x)|^2 dx$. $F$ should be differentiable as it is a norm induced by a scalar product in a Hilbert space. We have

$$
\lim _{\|h\| \rightarrow 0} \frac{|\int_\mathbb R |f(x)+h(x)|^2 - |f(x)|^2 dx-A_f (h)|}{\|h\|_{L^2}}=0
$$

What should $A_f$ be ? I would like the answer to include a heuristic to find $A_f$, so I could compute other Fréchet derivatives in $L^2$, for example the one of $F(f)=\int_\mathbb R |f(x)|^4 dx$.

Comment: $A_f(g)$ is an element of $W$, but what you've written in your second line is a real number.

Comment: The norm squared in $L^2$ or any Hilbert Space for that matter is $\langle x , x \rangle$, which is the inner product of $x$ with itself. In case of $\mathbb{R}^d$, the derivative of this map ($x \cdot x  = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2)$ is $2x$. Can you conjecture what the derivative would then be in the case of $L^2$?

Comment: it is not clear what $g$ is in the second equality for a general Banach space

Comment: @W.Volante: $L_2\not\subset\mathcal{L}_4$

Answer (score 2):

If one consider real valued functions, i.e. $L_2(X;\mathbb{R})$ with
$\langle f,g\rangle =\int fg\,d\mu$

Then

$$F(f+h)=\langle f+h,f+h\rangle = \langle f,f\rangle + 2\langle f,h\rangle +\langle h,h\rangle=F(f)+2\langle f,h\rangle + F(h)
$$

Cearly, $h\mapsto \langle f,h\rangle$ is linear, and
$\frac{F(h)}{\|h\|_2}\xrightarrow{\|h\|_2\rightarrow0}0$. From this, it follows that
$$F'(f)h=2\langle f,h\rangle$$

Comment: Thank you, what about my first question about the definition ?

Comment: Also, I agree with you comment about $L^4$, but what about something like $F(f)=\int_\mathbb R |f'(x)|^2 dx$, what would the heuristic be ?

Comment: Actually, shouldn't  $A_f= \langle \frac{f}{||f||},.\rangle$ ?

Comment: Your definition of differentiability is equivalent to $F(x+h) =F(x) + Ah+o(\|h\|)$ where $A$ is linear.

Comment: Not every L2 function has a derivative ( in the classical or in the L_2 sense)

Comment: Of course, but $F$ in the general definition is defined on $U$, not $V$

Comment: U and V open. $L_2\cap L_4$ is not open in $L_2$.